# Can I rename Flyway migration scripts?

Tags: flyway

I have a project whose database is managed by Flyway in strict validation mode.
My migration files look like this:

- V1.0__init.sql
- V11.0__even_better.sql
- V2.0__update.sql
- V7.0__enhance.sql

The files are not displayed in the correct order (11 is between 1 and 2).
Therefore I would like to change them to look like:

- V001.000__init.sql
- V002.000__update.sql
- V007.000__enhance.sql
- V011.000__even_better.sql

The [documentation says](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/):

> Leading zeroes are ignored in each part

This could mean that the above renamings are ok.
But looking at the `schema_version` table, the leading zeroes are kept, which seems like the above renamings would break the migration. So can I do the renaming, or will it blow up everything?

Comment: Have you put anything into production or do you just have "local" migrations so far?

Comment: Perhaps a bit off-topic, but note that the GNU `ls` command supports sorting by version number, which works well with the Flyway file names convention. Just try `ls -lv` to get your migration files sorted by version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying it locally, it just worked.

The reason why I didn’t expect that is that the version numbers in the `schema_version` table include the leading zeroes, and the `script` column also mentions the original script in its full name.

But despite of that, validation succeeded after renaming the files.